# Can't make foudantion-rails gem work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, zurb-foundation-6

SW Versions:

- ruby 2.3.0
- rails 4.2.5.1
- foundation-rails 6.2.0.1

I'm using the foundation-rails gem in an empty rails app with just a basic scaffold controller, model and views. I installed it following [these instructions](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails) in the gem gitHub page. I get the basic Foundation markup (links, tables, buttons...), but any other stuff doesn't work, for example, if i try to insert a side navigation menu using this code (from the foundation website):

```
<ul class="side-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I get this:

[image]

The foundation css file generated from the scss files is [here](https://gist.github.com/Pizzicato/3349297e9af9fbd89c7d90dc186518e4)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to version 6.2.1 fixed the issue

Comment: Any idea what the root cause was?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. I couldn't find the cause, also I didn't find any issue in their github page to appoint this problem :-S

Comment: Well, if a gem feels painful and the doctor says don't use that gem, I'll do as my doctor tells me. : )